# Scaling Akka ActorSystem

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

I have an Actor System in a cluster with a filecollectorActor and a DecoderActor. It works fine on single machine and gives expected performance. Now, I want to test the scalability by running the same on two servers.

How do I run the actors so that both the CPUs are used?Do I need to make a Supervisor actor kind of thing on two servers and then start the actor cluster?

How can I define seed nodes with different IPs?

If you think the question is vague, either direct me to a doc (couldnt get answer on akka doc), or example or please ask a clarification question.

Thanks,

-Saket